# What is the word/phrase for a person at a company that has very specific knowledge and nobody else at the company does?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

This is a bad thing — that is, the knowledge is concentrated to one person.

I want to say it is *tribal knowledge*, but those words aren't correct.

> It is definitely _______ knowledge.

I just can't think of the word that goes in that blank!

Comment: The positive version of this phenomenon is sometimes called *institutional knowledge*; i.e., the knowledge that only comes from having a great deal of experience and longevity with the organization. More to your point, however, tchrist's answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any number of synonyms you’ll find for this idea, including such words as *sequestered, restricted, secluded, isolated, compartmentalized, firewalled, hidden, squirrelled-away*, and *walled-off*.

But if you’re playing *Buzzword Bingo™ for Annoying Business Jargon<sup>®</sup>* at this year’s office Christmas party, the word you’re probably looking for is ***siloed***. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/silo#silo) says the verb means to

> Isolate (one system, process, department, etc.) from others.

They provide many examples, the first two of which are:

> - ‘most companies have expensive IT systems they have developed over the years, but they are siloed’
> - ‘why are so many companies still siloing their SEO and social media marketing

The thing to remember with using *silo* and *siloed* this way is that this is a trendy bit of business jargon that business people use to make them seem hip and with it, all because they think it’s terminology that’s all the rage right now — without realizing they may risk coming off as pretentious and vapid to people who aren’t into that sort of ephemeral bingo-lingo.

Comment: Excellent answer, tchrist. I'd give you more than one up-vote if I could!

Answer (score 2):

That employee is often referred to as a subject-matter expert (SME), or generally, a pinpoint specialist or expert. They possess unique knowledge or experience in a given topic or task that makes them the sole (or primary) source of information or point of performance, or single-point-of-failure, or the go-to, on that topic.

This condition is great for job security of that individual if the unique expertise is in a productive function for the company and effectively moves the company forward, but as others pointed out it isolates talent in one individual — what happens if the SME is not able to come to work? A talent/knowledge vacuum is created as talent redundancy has been overlooked and nobody else knows how to do Sara's job, then that leg of the company experiences failure until a solution for Sara's absence is resolved.